# How do I fix the println function?

Tags: kotlin

I was trying to make the Pythagorean theorem and it wasn't working, I tried fixing it but I finally compressed the error into a single line of code.

```
package kotlin.math
fun pythag(a: Int , b: Int){
    var c = sqrt((a*a) + (b*b)
    print(c.toDouble()))
}

fun main() { 
    pythag(6, 3)
}
```

Errors:
Unresolved reference: println
Unresolved reference: c
I'm not sure how the issue is found, but it's definitely a syntax error
pls fix no work

Comment: You have a missing parentheses on the `sqrt` line and an extra parentheses at the end of the `print` method invocation.

Comment: The title asks about `println()` while the code has `print()`. And it's unlikely to be a good idea to declare your code in the existing `kotlin.math` package — did you mean to `import` (something from) that instead?

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a `)` on your third line.
That's why the compiler doesn't know of the variable`c`, because the assignment is not completed.

Change

```kotlin
var c = sqrt((a*a) + (b*b)
print(c.toDouble()))
```

to

```kotlin
var c = sqrt((a*a) + (b*b))
print(c.toDouble())
```

Comment: Now it is giving me a type mismatch error saying that it expected a double

Answer (score 1):

You have some syntax error and type mismatch error because `sqrt` function takes double not int

```kotlin
fun pythag(a: Int , b: Int) {
    val c = sqrt(((a*a) + (b*b)).toDouble())
    print(c)
}

fun main() {
    pythag(6, 3)
}
```

or change `pythag` function to take 2 doubles

```kotlin
fun pythag(a: Double , b: Double) {
    val c = sqrt((a*a) + (b*b))
    print(c)
}

fun main() {
    pythag(6.0, 3.0)
}
```